# Finding the mode of an array Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've got to find the mode of an array.  I am a bit embarrassed to admit that I've been stuck on this for a day.  I think I've overthought it a bit - my method just gets longer and longer.  The real issue that I keep running into is that when there isn't *one* mode (two numbers appear with the same frequency) I need to return Double.NaN.

Here's what I've tried:

```
private double[] data = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9};

if(data.length != 0){

        double maxValue = -1;
        int maxCount = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                if(data[j] == data[i]) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if(count > maxCount) {
                maxValue = (int) data[i];
                maxCount = count;
            }
        }
        return maxValue;

    }else{

        return Double.NaN;

    }
```

This actually returns the mode, but it can't deal with two modes.  Here's my most recent attempt, but it's only half complete:

```
private double[] data = {1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9};

public void mode(){

    int[] frequency = new int[data.length];

    double[] vals = new double[data.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        frequency[i] = occursNumberOfTimes(data[i]);
    }

    boolean uniform = false;

    for(int g = 0; g < frequency.length && !uniform; g++){
        if(frequency[0] != frequency[g]){
            uniform = false;
        }

    int[] arr = new int[frequency.length-1];

    for(int j = 1; j < frequency.length; j++){

        if(frequency[j] > frequency[j-1]){

            int mod = 0;

            for(int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++){
                if(k == j){
                    mod += 1;
                    arr[k] = frequency[k + mod];
                }else{
                    arr[k] = frequency[k + mod];    
                }
            }
        }
    }
    frequency = arr;
    }
}

private int occursNumberOfTimes(double value){

    int count = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        if(data[i] == value){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

I sorta got lost in the second try, I just can't sort out how to deal with multiple modes.  I've written out my thoughts, but I just don't know how.  **I can't use anything from the Arrays class, which is why I'm lost.**

Comment: **"Can't use anything from the Arrays class"**  I assume this also includes anything from `Collection` including`Set` and `Map`?

Comment: Where is `data` defined?  What does it contain?  May we see?

Comment: Assuming the answer to the above is "yes", then I think the best way to proceed is to break down the problem into smaller chunks, and implements something on its own like `Map` (you can look at that class and steal ideas) and then once you have your own version working the rest should be relatively easy.

Comment: Without using other collections, the easiest way might be to sort the array and then count the longest consecutive sequence of a single int value.

Comment: Just take your working implementation and modify it to track the top *two* most common elements. At the end of the loop, check to see if both those counts are the same -- and if they are return a NaN.

Comment: @markspace Yup, can't use any of that.

Comment: @Makoto Sorry I forgot to add that.  I have now.  It's just an array of numbers.  It could be longs, floats, doubles, etc..

Comment: @flakes I assume I'd have to sort that array with loops, as I can't use Arrays.sort.  I sorta run into the same issue there though - I don't really know how to deal with two modes.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Okay.  That makes sense.  I'm not entirely sure how to do that, but I'll certainly try.  I may have to come back here in a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it have to be efficient? If not:

```
double maxValue = -1.0d;
int maxCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    double currentValue = data[i];
    int currentCount = 1;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < data.length; ++j) {
        if (Math.abs(data[j] - currentValue) < epsilon) {
            ++currentCount;
        } 
    }
    if (currentCount > maxCount) {
        maxCount = currentCount;
        maxValue = currentValue;
    } else if (currentCount == maxCount) {
        maxValue = Double.NaN;
    }
}
System.out.println("mode: " + maxValue);
```

Comment: Wow!  I just sat for a few hours writing my own solution, but this is way better.  Thank you!  I think I know what's going on by looking at it, but I don't think I could have ever come up with this.  I was just thinking about it so differently - sort of overcomplicating it.

Comment: Hello Can I ask what the line `if (Math.abs(data[j] - currentValue) < epsilon) {` is doing?

Comment: Thanks Samuel. Fixed it: float point comparisons use a tolerance, or epsilon.

Answer (score 0):

You could track the two most common elements as was suggested in the comments, but another approach is to keep a boolean flag that indicates if the current most common element is unique. Then:

1. For each array element `e`, obtain its count as you're currently doing.
2. If that count is greater than the current max, set the the most common element (seen so far) to `e` and set the "unique" flag to `true`.
3. Otherwise, if that count is equal to the current max, set the "unique" flag to `false`.

At the end, just return the mode if "unique" is `true`, otherwise return `NaN`.

Comment: Okay.  I just wrote a super long solution that does work but doesn't use that.  I really don't think my solution is good, but I'm happy that it at least works.  I think I'll try this approach soon just to understand it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my long, dumb solution.  It works!  It's a very roundabout way of getting the mode, but I'm really happy it works.  I used the advice I got from some comments and looked at it differently.  It was a frustrating few hours, but here it is:

```
public double mode2(){



    if(data.length != 0){

        int[] counts = new int[data.length];
        double[] vals = new double[data.length];

        for(int l = 0; l < data.length; l++){

            counts[l] = 1;

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j < data.length; j++){

                if((data[i] == data[j]) && (i != j)){

                    vals[i] = data[i];
                    counts[i] += 1;

                }

            }

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j < data.length; j++){

                if((vals[i] == vals[j]) && (i != j)){

                    vals[i] = 0;
                    counts[i] = 0;

                }

            }
        }

        int counter = 0;

        for(int k = 0; k < data.length; k++){

            if(counts[k] != 0){

                counts[counter] = counts[k];
                vals[counter] = vals[k];
                counter++;

            }

        }


        int[] compactCounts = new int[counter];
        double[] compactVals = new double[counter];

        for(int k = 0; k < counter; k++){

            if(counts[k] != 0){

                compactCounts[k] = counts[k];
                compactVals[k] = vals[k];

            }else{

                break;

            }

        }

        for(int g = 1; g < compactVals.length; g++){

            if(compactCounts[g] > compactCounts[g-1]){

                compactCounts[g-1] = 0;
                compactVals[g-1] = 0;

            }

        }

        for(int g = 0; g < compactVals.length-1; g++){

            if(compactCounts[g] > compactCounts[g+1]){

                compactCounts[g+1] = 0;
                compactVals[g+1] = 0;

            }

        }

        int counterTwo = 0;

        for(int k = 0; k < compactCounts.length; k++){

            if(compactCounts[k] != 0){

                compactCounts[counterTwo] = compactCounts[k];
                compactVals[counterTwo] = vals[k];
                counterTwo++;

            }

        }



        int[] compactCountsTwo = new int[counterTwo];
        double[] compactValsTwo = new double[counterTwo];

        for(int k = 0; k < counterTwo; k++){

            if(counts[k] != 0){

                compactCountsTwo[k] = compactCounts[k];
                compactValsTwo[k] = compactVals[k];

            }else{

                break;

            }
        }

        //now populated compactTwos

        //We're now setting some lesser values to 0

        for(int g = 1; g < compactValsTwo.length; g++){

            if(compactCountsTwo[g] > compactCountsTwo[g-1]){

                compactCountsTwo[g-1] = 0;
                compactValsTwo[g-1] = 0;

            }

        }


        //now setting other lesser values to 0


        for(int g = 0; g < compactValsTwo.length-1; g++){
            if(compactCountsTwo[g] > compactCountsTwo[g+1]){
                compactCountsTwo[g+1] = 0;
                compactValsTwo[g+1] = 0;

            }

        }


        //calling methods to shorten our arrays by dropping indexes populated by zeroes

        compactValsTwo = doubleTruncator(compactValsTwo);
        compactCountsTwo = intTruncator(compactCountsTwo);


        //now setting some lesser values to 0

        for(int g = 1; g < compactValsTwo.length; g++){

            if(compactCountsTwo[g] > compactCountsTwo[g-1]){

                compactCountsTwo[g-1] = 0;
                compactValsTwo[g-1] = 0;

            }

        }


        //now setting other lesser values to 0


        for(int g = 0; g < compactValsTwo.length-1; g++){
            if(compactCountsTwo[g] > compactCountsTwo[g+1]){
                compactCountsTwo[g+1] = 0;
                compactValsTwo[g+1] = 0;

            }

        }


        //calling methods to shorten our arrays by dropping indexes populated by zeroes

        compactValsTwo = doubleTruncator(compactValsTwo);
        compactCountsTwo = intTruncator(compactCountsTwo);


        if(compactValsTwo.length > 1){

            return Double.NaN;

        }else{

            return compactValsTwo[0];

        }

        }else{

            System.out.println("ISSUE");
            return Double.NaN;          
    }   
}


public double[] doubleTruncator(double[] a){

    int counter = 0;

    for(int k = 0; k < a.length; k++){

        if(a[k] != 0){

            a[counter] = a[k];
            counter++;

        }

    }

    double[] b = new double[counter];

    for(int i= 0; i < counter; i++){

        if(a[i] != 0){

            b[i] = a[i];

        }else{

            break;

        }

    }
    return b;

}


public int[] intTruncator(int[] a){

    int counter = 0;

    for(int k = 0; k < a.length; k++){

        if(a[k] != 0){

            a[counter] = a[k];
            counter++;

        }

    }

    int[] b = new int[counter];

    for(int i= 0; i < counter; i++){

        if(a[i] != 0){

            b[i] = a[i];

        }else{

            break;

        }

    }
    return b;

}
```

Big thanks to everybody who helped.  I know it's not great (certainly not as good as the answer from @Perdi Estaquel), but I'm happy that I managed to do it.